# External USB drive keeps unmounting and remounting using different UUID

Tags: usb, mount, uuid

I got a 10TB external drive that I use for backups. I normally mount it using fstab and identifying it by its UUID.

However, recently it started unmounting spontaneously - and then remounting using its UUID with an added digit. I have uncommented the entry in fstab and now just trying to work with its own ideas of what the mount points should be. However, they are not consistent and they change all the time.

Below are outputs from df and ls. I have also attached a screenshot from gparted.[image: gparted showing mount point is different to the UUID]

```
ro@DAW:/media$ df
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc2       916G  509G  361G  59% /
/dev/sdb1       1.8T  484G  1.3T  28% /media/data
/dev/sda2       1.8T  1.4T  346G  81% /media/multimedia
/dev/sda3       1.8T  332G  1.4T  20% /media/extra
/dev/sdd1       9.1T  6.9T  1.7T  81% /media/ro/7d5fa3af-26e4-4de5-85d6-7018a84096462
ro@DAW:/media$ cd ro
ro@DAW:/media/ro$ ls -ltra
total 20
drwx------   3 root root 4096 Mar  3 13:03 7d5fa3af-26e4-4de5-85d6-7018a8409646
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root 4096 Mar  3 16:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root 4096 Mar  3 16:35 7d5fa3af-26e4-4de5-85d6-7018a84096462
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Mar  3 18:00 7d5fa3af-26e4-4de5-85d6-7018a84096461
drwxr-x---+  5 root root 4096 Mar  3 18:14 .
ro@DAW:/media/ro$
```

Grateful for any hints as to what I should try.

Comment: Please post `dmesg` and `journalctl -b` output. It could be a faulty USB cable randomly disconnecting, have you tried another cable?